# Debian using llvmpipe drivers instead of nvidia drivers

Tags: debian, xorg, nvidia, graphics, proprietary-drivers

Recently I have been trying to play Minecraft on my computer, it has been running slow at 20 fps and when I looked at the debug information it said it was using llvmpipe mesa compatibility drivers. I have a Nvidia card specifically an GT630 or GF108 variant (Fermi)

I installed my drivers with the .run drivers and the drivers i use are nvidia 390 legacy drivers. I can use multiple monitors without problems.

glxinfo output:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Mesa/X.org
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.6, 256 bits)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 22.3.1
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.5 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 22.3.1
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 22.3.1
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

I use xfce4 4.18 and kernel 6.0.0-6

Comment: Welcome to Unix. It is best to include the actual debugging information in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it, by installing the nvidia legacy 390xx drivers from the debian repository. Now games run fast without issues